# Electron Packager creates errors in the packaged file

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I am packaging my application into EXE file using electron-packager by using the following command:

`electron-packager ./ --overwrite --platform=win32 --out=./release/`

But I am getting the following error when I run the generated EXE file: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uESKZ.png)

May I know what causes the problem?

Comment: A guess: try changing `--out=./release/` to this `--out=release`

Comment: thank you but I am still getting the same error message